# Looking for pseudo code for hashing algorithms (open, chaining and multiple)

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, pseudocode

Greetings, I am looking for the pseudo code for "open", "chaining" abd "multiple hashing" algorithms. Yes I have been searching for a good amount of time at google but I wasn't able to get something good.

If you have a link to share, I will be greatful

regards

Answer (score 3):

This [hash table tutorial](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) has examples of open and chaining collision resolution.

[Bob Jenkins' Web Site](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/) has further examples of hash tables, perfect hashes and efficient hash functions.

I haven't found a satisfying explanation of multiple hashing (specifically why combining two different 32 bit hashes is considered better than a smooth 64 bit hash)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

And from there:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA_hash_functions#Examples_and_pseudocode

etc.